# boost.asio read many packets

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

I'm newest in boost asio. I write program for VoIP. But I dont understand how I can write many packets. That's my code.

Microphone.

```
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data,val*2),error);
```

every 10ms in while

Speaker

```
accepter.accept(socket);
while (true)
{
    bool is_open = socket.is_open();
    if (!is_open) break;
    //cout<<"Connected"<<endl;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::array <char, 441> buffer;    
    size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer),error);
    //Play buffer sound
    cout.write(buffer.data(),441); //for check

}
```

If i start 2 programs, In console I see repeating charater set. What I need to do?

Comment: what do you mean by "packages"?#

Comment: @TonyTheLion it's the Runglish for "packets"

Comment: You are not checking the error code in your while loop, have you tried in a debugger to see if there is an error, or better yet, just check for it in your code? an error would cause your buffer to remain unchanged, causing the "repeating character set". Assuming that with *repeating character set* you mean that you have the same buffer contents in every iteration.